# What is NetBeans's Ctrl+I shortcut equivalent in Eclipse?

Tags: java, oop, ide, shortcut

In the video that I'm using to learn Java, I discovered that in NetBeans you can generate getter and setter methods using this shortcut, and I want to do it too, but I'm using Eclipse.

I tried googling it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Ctrl+1 brings up the quick fix.

Comment: Use intelliJ from jetbrains

Comment: you can use (SHIFT + ALT + S) to generate getter/setter or constructor with fields or equals and hash code

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple options:

- **Ctrl+1** -> **Create getter and setter for '*variable*'...** like Robert said
- **menu Source** -> **Generate Getters and Setters...** (same as **Alt+S**, then **R**)
- **Alt+Shift+S**, then **R**

**Ctrl+1** is mostly used when you're generating just one (because it's used for many many other things as well), but the menu option is better when you're generating several at once.